# Serialize array of derived type property of derived type

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I've got a simple .Net framework C# console app that serializes a a class that is of a derived type, where a property is also of a derived type.

The derived classes have names that are the same as the base class, but are in a different namespace to prevent them from clashing. It seems though that the reflection the `XmlSerializer` uses does not work with this too well. Maybe there is some way of wrangling the attributes that I can still end up with the base class using pretty names (as it will be a DLL interface when used) and the XML also using pretty names (as it will be human editable)... pretty names for the derived classes are not required (though would be a bonus).

The XML would hopefully look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Details>
    <Detail>
      <Description>bald</Description>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Description>red tie</Description>
    </Detail>
  </Details>
</Person>
```

But the closest I can get without exceptions is where the `<Detail>` elements are

```
    <Detail xsi:type="DerivedDetail"> ... </Detail>
```

Having to add this `xs:type` attribute is not the best for human-editable XML.

This is achieved with the below C# code. If I remove the marked `XmlType` attribute then the element *should* serialize without the `xsi:type` attribute, but instead I get an exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Types 'Test.Detail' and 'Test.Xml.Detail' both use the XML type name, 'Detail', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

I tried marking the derived `Xml.Detail` class as an anonymous XML type but then the exception reads:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot include anonymous type 'Test.Xml.Detail'.

I have read many similar questions but have not encountered anything that solves this just yet.

In this code below `Person` is an abstract class that has a property that is an array of the abstract type `Detail`. These types are derived by `Xml.Person` and `Xml.Detail` respectively. The program creates a test `Xml.Person` object and attempts to serialize it:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create test details array
            var TestDetails = new Xml.Detail[] 
            {
                new Xml.Detail
                {
                    Description = "bald"
                },
                new Xml.Detail
                {
                    Description = "red tie"
                }
            };

            // create test person object that holds details array
            var TestBar = new Xml.Person()
            {
                Details = TestDetails
            };

            // serialize the person object
            var s = new Xml.Serializer();
            var TestOutput = s.Serialize(TestBar);

            Console.WriteLine(TestOutput);
        }
    }

    // base classes
    public abstract class Person
    {
        public abstract Detail[] Details { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Detail
    {
        public abstract string Description { get; set; }
    }

    namespace Xml
    {
        // derived classes
        [Serializable]
        [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
        [XmlRoot(IsNullable = false)]
        public class Person : Test.Person
        {
            [XmlArrayItem("Detail", typeof(Detail))]
            [XmlArray(IsNullable = false)]
            public override Test.Detail[] Details { get; set; }
        }

        // This attribute makes serialization work but also adds the xsi:type attribute
        [XmlType("DerivedDetail")]
        [Serializable]
        public class Detail : Test.Detail
        {
            public override string Description { get; set; }
        }

        // class that does serializing work
        public class Serializer
        {
            private static XmlSerializer PersonSerializer = 
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person), new Type[] { typeof(Detail) });

            public string Serialize(Test.Person person)
            {
                string Output = null;
                var Stream = new MemoryStream();
                var Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

                using (var Writer = new XmlTextWriter(Stream, Encoding))
                {
                    Writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    PersonSerializer.Serialize(Writer, person);
                    Output = Encoding.GetString(Stream.ToArray());
                }
                Stream.Dispose();
                return Output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that trying the naming the other way around, naming the derived class as `DerivedDetail` and removing the `XmlType` attribute, still results in a similar `xsi:type` attribute on the serialized element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're using base classes instead of interfaces when you don't have any member fields. Regardless, I assumed you wanted `Xml.Person` to be a concrete instantiation of abstract `Person` or any classes derived from abstract `Person` without decorating abstract `Person` with XML attributes. I accomplished this by forcing abstract `Person` to become a concrete instantiation of `Xml.Person` before serializing it. Please replace `XmlSerializationProject` with `Test`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerializationProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create test details array
            var TestDetails = new Xml.Detail[]
            {
                new Xml.Detail
                {
                    Description = "bald"
                },
                new Xml.Detail
                {
                    Description = "red tie"
                }
            };

            // create test person object that holds details array
            var TestBar = new Xml.Person()
            {
                Details = TestDetails
            };

            // serialize the person object
            var s = new Xml.Serializer();
            var TestOutput = s.Serialize(TestBar);

            Console.WriteLine(TestOutput);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    // base classes
    public abstract class Person
    {
        public abstract Detail[] Details { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Detail
    {
        public abstract string Description { get; set; }
    }

    namespace Xml
    {
        [Serializable]
        [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
        [XmlRoot(IsNullable = false)]
        public class Person : XmlSerializationProject.Person
        {
            public Person()
            { }

            public Person(XmlSerializationProject.Person person)
            {
                // Deep copy
                if (person.Details == null) return;
                this.Details = new Detail[person.Details.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < person.Details.Length; i++)
                {
                    this.Details[i] = new Detail { Description = person.Details[i].Description };
                }
            }

            [XmlArray(ElementName = "Details")]
            [XmlArrayItem("Detail", typeof(Detail))]
            [XmlArrayItem("ODetail", typeof(XmlSerializationProject.Detail))]
            public override XmlSerializationProject.Detail[] Details
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class Detail : XmlSerializationProject.Detail
        {
            public override string Description { get; set; }
        }

        // class that does serializing work
        public class Serializer
        {
            private static readonly XmlSerializer PersonSerializer;

            private static Serializer()
            {
                var xmlAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
                // Change original "Detail" class's element name to "AbstractDetail"
                var xmlAttributesOriginalDetail = new XmlAttributes();
                xmlAttributesOriginalDetail.XmlType = new XmlTypeAttribute() { TypeName = "AbstractDetail" };
                xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(XmlSerializationProject.Detail), xmlAttributesOriginalDetail);

                // Ignore Person.Details array
                var xmlAttributesOriginalDetailsArray = new XmlAttributes();
                xmlAttributesOriginalDetailsArray.XmlIgnore = true;
                xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(XmlSerializationProject.Person), "Details", xmlAttributesOriginalDetailsArray);

                PersonSerializer = new XmlSerializer(
                    typeof(Person), xmlAttributeOverrides, new Type[] { typeof(Detail) }, new XmlRootAttribute(), "default");
            }

            public string Serialize(XmlSerializationProject.Person person)
            {
                return Serialize(new Person(person));
            }

            public string Serialize(Person person)
            {
                string Output = null;
                var Stream = new MemoryStream();
                var Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

                using (var Writer = new XmlTextWriter(Stream, Encoding))
                {
                    Writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    PersonSerializer.Serialize(Writer, person);
                    Output = Encoding.GetString(Stream.ToArray());
                }
                Stream.Dispose();
                return Output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TBH interfaces made more sense to me but but couldn't get them to work. All the examples I could find used inheritance instead so I switched to that. Your code works great! one small thing though; there's a *`private`* `static` constructor in `Serializer` class? Access modifiers are not allowed on static constructors IIRC.

Comment: Had to look that up. You are correct, but it compiles. I guess static constructors are private if you think about it.

Comment: It compiles? Wow, my VS2017 wouldn't even get that far, got a syntax error immediately on it I've noticed. I removed the `private` and it works fine though.

Comment: I was using vs 2012

Comment: I've since got interfaces working anyway, yay! This helped significantly in getting there :)